# Powershell stays in memory

Tags: powershell, windows-installer

I'm running this simple script of MSIEXEC uninstall:

```
 $script = { 
  invoke-expression "msiexec /qn /x '{C5CF41A6-A65A-4BB3-8C6C-87FF4A730EFD}' "
  $logcheck = ""
  while($true)
  {   
    if($logcheck -match "Removal success or error status: 0")
    {
      return
    }
    else
    {
      start-sleep -Seconds 1
   [string]$logcheck = get-eventlog -logname application -newest 1 | foreach-object {$_.message}
    }
  }
}

Invoke-Command -computername Comp-name -Credential Domain\user -scriptblock $script
Write-Host "Done"
```

Everything seems to work great, the MSI was being uninstalled successfully but the powershell process stays open and doesn't stop.

Any idea how can I stop it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't stop because of the `while($true)`

That logcheck is not really full proof, it gets the newest log item and then checks for status "Removal success or error status: 0". If any other application adds an entry to the log at the same time, this loop will run forever.

Better to get all log items since a certain date, e.g. start datetime of msiexec and look for the success message. (and not use the loop)